# New product import not visible front end but have back end

Tags: magento, import, magento-1.9

When i import product through excel, the products at back end but not visible at front end, the thing is, when i save the product manually then only the product display at front end. How can i manually save all products, it's waste my time.

Comment: are you going to import product via any extension?

Comment: after importing product through excel check this attribute value http://prntscr.com/c81bi1

Comment: ya, am set right, but not visible at front, but am go to products edit page just click save button without any changes, after asking clear cache, i did clear cache, after only products visible at front,

Comment: why not asking clear cache when i import bulk products,

Comment: only visible the products after clear cache, the thing is am clear cache manually after import bulk products, no use

Comment: pls help me escape from this error,

Comment: you mean that when you import in bulk and clear the cache its showing products on front or not?

Comment: bro, the error is, when i import bulk products, the products have back end and not visible front end, then i have idea, go to one product edit page just click save button without any changes, right after only visible at front end

Comment: the thing is magento can't completely recognized my products,

Comment: is any server error ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in your case, Products visible in frontend only when manually save the product, you can save all the products once,by `Catalog > Manage Products` , select `Actions` under `updtate attributes` & than select `Catalog, Search` under `Visibility` & save it. link : [here](http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-update-attribute-sets-in-bulk.html#gref)

Comment: is all your indexes are in `Ready mode` or `processing` ?

Comment: may be you need to find solution for this, if you have ssh access , you can try with ssh

Comment: why it will skip, if you entered correctly in excel sheet and upload 99 % no chances of skipping..... try once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121528/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-nsdlfefinedieicbe).

Answer (score 0):

Reason why your product do not show in fronend is because magento load products from index. Check your catalog_product_flat_* whether product is present or not. 
Please run the indexing after your product upload. This you can be find under

```
system/index management menu.
```

Comment: Yes, i am reindex after my import done, still not visible at front end, and images also placed catalog_product_flat_*

Comment: What is the status & mode of indexing related to category & products indexing ?

Comment: still on processing

Comment: when it will completed, in my store  30,000 products are there

Comment: so issue is with indexing. Do you have ssh access to ur server ?

Comment: how can i use ssh

Comment: Are you doing this in your local system or on server ? If server then what server is it ? also which operating system do you use ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121694/discussion-between-jeeva-rathinam-and-rajatsaurastri).

Comment: @ chat : am waiting there